# runtime error when the list.clear() was called

Tags: c++, windows, list, stl

I want to simulate the C# Event-Driven Programming in Windows Programming with C++.

I want to accomplish that in this way :

1. use a list container to save function pointers
2. override the += operator, make the class Event can add function in
   this way **event+=handlerFuncName**
3. override the () operator, so we can call the function in list

Event class:

```
template<class Sender_Type, class Args_Type>
class Event{
private:
    typedef void(*HFUN)(Sender_Type *, Args_Type);
    list<HFUN> handlers;
public:
    void operator +=(HFUN handler){
        handlers.push_back(handler);
    }

    void operator ()(Sender_Type *sender, Args_Type e){       
        for (list<HFUN>::iterator it = handlers.begin(); it != handlers.end(); it++)
            (*it)(sender, e);
    }

    ~Event(){ printf("Release..\n"); }
};
```

and here is a instance :

the definition of EventArgs class and the window class:

```
class EventArgs{ };

class Win32Window
{
public:
    // event definition
    Event<Win32Window, EventArgs> Loaded;

    // ctor
    Win32Window(){
        // ...
        // trigger the Loaded event
        Loaded(this, EventArgs());
    }
    // ...
};
```

the definition of the event handler function:

```
void Window_Loaded(Win32Window *sender, EventArgs e){
    MessageBox(NULL, "Window_Loaded", "xx", 0);
}
```

main function:

```
Win32Window wnd;
//add the event handler function
wnd.Loaded += Window_Loaded;
```

It works but when the window was closing, there was runtime error in `list.clear()`!
Here is a [snapshot](https://6zf0hw.bn1304.livefilestore.com/y2pyHhjlEMSWnE4xuSB2nWb1yF3SmYPoiKYGp3TFgiSqbNb896-2AYWJqhv50mpc8ZdcOcrOjGuvlGZhMqTd2O-7Xt2kU35SAgPSr4p7TvOlOU/20131216192636.jpg?psid=1) of exception:

Comment: Can't even see you image ...

Comment: What is HFUN? Can you show the code that initialises and clears this list, the matter of the event handler code isn't necessary. Try and reduce ths to an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) please.

Comment: Member function pointers are clearly not the answer. Try to read up on Functors.

Comment: typedef void(*HFUN)(Sender_Type *, Args_Type);  I haven't called the clear() function. I think it was called automaticly when the list was releasing. all operation to the list(handlers) was showed in these codes, there is no any more operation to it.

Comment: using `std::function` would definitely make this easier to read.. and be safer

Comment: I don't know about Functors and std::function, since I am new on C++. I'm trying. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is, I think, precisely the kind of problem that `std::function` was intended to help with. Try something like this for starters:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename Sender, typename... Args>
class Event
{
    using FuncType = std::function<void(Sender&, Args...)>;
    std::vector<FuncType> vec;

public:
    Event& operator+=(FuncType f) {
        vec.push_back(f);
        return *this;
    }

    void operator()(Sender& s, Args... a) {
        for (auto& f : vec) {
            f(s, a...);
        }
    }
};


struct Window
{
    Event<Window, int, int> resized;

    void resize(int width, int height) {
        // blah blah
        resized(*this, width, height);
    }

};

int main()
{
    Window w;

    w.resized += [](Window&, int w, int h) {
        std::cout << "Window resized to " << w << " by " << h << std::endl;
    };

    w.resize(800, 600);
}
```

Note that this method allows you to not only use regular functions as event handers, but also lambdas (as demonstrated), and also function objects.